# Dynamically set SKAction delay time

Tags: ios, skaction

I have a SKAction delay defined as :-

```
let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(delayInSecs))
```

It is used in a sequence with other Action

```
let doStuffThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([doStuff, delay])
let doStuffThenDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(doStuffThenDelay)
self.runAction(doStuffThenDelayForever)
```

How can I dynamically adjust the delay time without creating a new SKAction?

I tried to do the following but it doesn't work.

```
delayTime = delayTime - 0.25
delay.duration = NSTimeInterval(delayTime)
```

Comment: You can create an SKAction with a randomly varying delay with waitForDuration:withRange, but I don't think there's a way to create a non-fixed, non-random delay without generating a new SKAction after each iteration.